# Convert time format 12 de Marzo 2014 05:51 pm

Tags: c#-3.0

i need to convert date to below spanish format in c#

**12 de Marzo 2014 05:51 pm**

please suggest

Comment: What's wrong with the output you're getting from `string.Format(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Start here and have a look around the documentation's abundant and useful functions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Then try:

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php
```

And sub in your desired language settings with logic/if statements

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you?

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("12 de Marzo 2014 05:51 pm");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Interaction.MsgBox(date.ToLongDateString());
```

OR

```
DateTimeFormatInfo espDtfi = new CultureInfo("es-ES", false).DateTimeFormat;
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;

string result = Convert.ToDateTime("12 de Marzo 2014 05:51 pm", espDtfi).ToString(usDtfi.ShortDatePattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() // hh:mm:ss xM
DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() // dayOfTheWeek, Month dd, yyyy
```